# Electric flux due to coaxial, non-conducting, uniformly charged discs

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, gauss-law

Recently I came across a question which involved two **coaxial, non conducting, uniformly charged discs**, each having a surface charge density $\sigma$.

I was required to find the *electric flux* through one disc due to the *electric field* of the *other disc* and vice-versa.

The solution somewhat confused me. It claimed that the **force exerted on one disc (say D1)** due to the *electric field* of another (**D2**)  is equal to $\sigma\phi$, where $\phi$ is the electric flux through **D1** due to the *electric field* of **D2**.

Is it possible that this statement always holds true?

In order to find the net flux, we must use the concept of *solid angle* and **Gauss Law**, but how can we always measure the angle here between *electric field* and *area* vectors?

Can someone explain this to me briefly (I'm not much seasoned with advanced math, I'm just a 12th grader!)?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reference or diagram of the context?

Comment: I've shared the question, you can check it out now.

Answer (score 0):

1)If you draw a gaussian cylinder from smaller disk to bigger one of radius $R$ ( radius of smaller disk),     now since they are coaxial -

2)So electric flux due to smaller disk on larger disk $\phi  = \cfrac{Q_{enc}}{2\epsilon o}$ (it is half because charge particle can be assumed as sphere with half portion on front and backward faces of disk)

3)Same formula goes for flux due to larger disk on smaller disk, for calculating flux only charge enclosed by  Gaussian surface is considered ,

4)On careful estimation you will find charges on both the flat faces of gaussian cylinder to be same ($Q_{enc} =\sigma \pi R^2$) , there is no need for electric field or area vector you could easily find enclosed charges by drawing symmetrical gaussian surfaces like cylinder over here.

5) Charge enclosed on both flat surfaces of gaussian cylinder is same so flux is same hence answer $1 :1$

Comment: I accept your reasoning, but aren't we commiting a big mistake in assuming a cylinder in such an asymmetric situation? If I draw a cylinder of radius R, should it cover the larger disc entirely? How do we go about the reasoning then? Gauss' surfaces were always about their symmetry(atleast I knew so).

Comment: @Abhinav Tahlani , the gaussian surface, and charge distribution should be symmetrical as it is in this case I have assumed , you can remove the  charges appearing outside gaussian surface( on disk face of radius 2r)   without any effect on flux , however field would change

Comment: Shouldn't the flux be spreading in a conical manner? Is it really so that we count the entire flux due to the smaller disc in this case? The electric flux due to a disc should be spreading everywhere throughout, and we just consider the flux passing through the surface of the larger disc here.